# How to get key of single datafram in spark joins

Tags: apache-spark

suppose I have 2 datasets like below

1. book

```
    case class Book(book_name: String, cost: Int, writer_id:Int)
    val bookDS = Seq(
    Book("Scala", 400, 1),
    Book("Spark", 500, 2),
    Book("Kafka", 300, 3),
    Book("Java", 350, 5)
    ).toDS()
    bookDS.show()
```

2. Writer

```
    case class Writer(writer_name: String, writer_id:Int)
    val writerDS = Seq(
    Writer("Martin",1),
    Writer("Zaharia " 2),
    Writer("Neha", 3),
    Writer("James", 4)
    ).toDS()
    writerDS.show()
```

When I inner join it it returns two times writer_id.

How can I get writer_id of only one dataset.
I don't want to write sql like select a.something,b.something.

Comment: Why have you mentioned python tag? It is pure scala code

Answer (score 0):

```
writerDS.join(bookDS, Seq("writer_id")).show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+----+
|writer_id|writer_name|book_name|cost|
+---------+-----------+---------+----+
|        1|     Martin|    Scala| 400|
|        2|    Zaharia|    Spark| 500|
|        3|       Neha|    Kafka| 300|
+---------+-----------+---------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

When we join two datasets all columns from both datasets will presetn in result dataset
So you can rename it and then drop one of those two column.

```
Dataset<Row> joinedDataset = bookDs
      .withcolumnRenamed(writer_id,book_writer_id)
      .join(writerDS,new Column(book_writer_id).equalTo(writer_id),"inner")
      .drop(book_writer_id);
```

Not sure if you are using python or scala.
Its a java code please convert it accordingly.